# How to interpret an image histogram and plot histogram3D for an image?

Tags: histograms

I'm really finding many ambiguities in how I really should interpret the histogram of an RGB image? I could understand what the height denotes, but did not understand how the pixels get plotted on a single dimensional x-axis. Also, is it possible to plot the image onto histogram3D? I tried after converting it to separate RGB images but I get an error that says it is not able to calculate the "bins" the diagram.

Thank you

Comment: Have you read the wiki link:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram . For the `Histogram3D` part, I can't really understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Collect `ImageData` using `'Byte'` type and you can see the pixel values clearly in `n*n*n` dimension. Loop to pick two from each set for `Histogram3D`. Each represents a color channel hence 3 per set. You can pick them separately and find simple `Historgram`. It shall match the below plotted onces.

Answer (score 6):

The default is to not show any useful labelling, so perhaps it might be easier to do this:

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];
ImageHistogram[i, FrameTicks -> {True, True}, 
 Appearance -> "Separated"]
```

[image: mandrill histogram]

For the 3D aspect of your question, perhaps you want something like this:

```
{r, g, b} = ColorSeparate[ImageResize[i, 200]]
ListPlot3D[ImageData[r, DataReversed -> True], Mesh -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> "GrayTones"]
```

[image: red channel of mandrill]

— this is just the red channel.

Answer (score 1):

This might be one more manual way to see `Histogram`.

```
image = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"]
tr = ImageData[image, "Byte"]
tr // Dimensions (*{116,150,3}*)
a = Table[tr[[i, j]] /. {a_, b_, c_} -> a, {i, 116}, {j, 150}](*Similarly for b,c)
```

Sample `Histogram` computation is

```
Histogram[b, 100, ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None],  ChartStyle -> Green]
```

Now comparing `Histogram` for a,b & c with `ImageHistogram` respectively. we shall see similar results.
[image]

We can see both of them resembling.
So, to calculate `Histogram3D` you need two coordinates which you can extract as,

```
ab = Table[tr[[i, j]] /. {a_, b_, c_} -> {a,b}, {i, 116}, {j, 150}]
(*Similarly for bc,ca)
```

My system is old so, I could produce it only once as it took long time. I am not pasting graphics for `Histogram3D` but you can generate it by `Histogram3D[ab]`.